# Multivariate normal cdf

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use the multivariate cdf through the command in [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html). I get an error saying the multivariate object has no cdf. The pdf is working fine however.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn

mean = np.array([0, 0])
covariance = np.array([[1, 0.4], [0.4, 1]])
mvna = mvn(mean, covariance)
print(mvna.cdf(np.array([-2, -4])))

multivariate_normal_frozen' object has no attribute 'cdf'
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: @Goyo: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Yes python 3.7.3 and python 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the version of scipy you are using is the same?  I am seeing other versions that do not have the cdf method.  Like in here: http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/scipy/0.17.1/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html